# in a stored procedure can I use query result in another query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Very new to stored procedures, I hope this makes sense.

I have a query that returns a set of values.  I want to take that set of values and use it in the where condition of another query.  For example:

This query

`select * from getgroups where field1 = true`

will return for me a list of groups available on the system.

for example:

| groupid |
| --- |
| aksdjfu |
| kdmcjku |
| dlkcpaa |

The next thing I need to do is pull the data about those groups using the query below, using the output from the first query in the where clause.

`select * from groups s where groupid = aksdjfu or groupid = kdmcjku or groupid = dlkcpaa`

I know I can send the data to a variable and then use it in a where condition what I don't know if how to craft the where condition with multiple options.

Comment: Have you considered doing a JOIN between `getgroups` and `groups`?